# Can't install software in raspbian

Tags: raspbian, raspi-config

Even run "sudo apt-get -f install" I got this error. Can't understand why?

```
      ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
      dpkg: error while cleaning up:
      subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
      Errors were encountered while processing:
      /var/cache/apt/archives/python-gi_3.8.2-1+rpi1rpi2_armhf.deb
```

Comment: What are you trying to install?

Answer (score 1):

Try not using the -f flag. It attempts to "fix-broken" to deduce what isn't working and either eliminate it or perform some other action. It should really only be used if you're troubleshooting a bad package install or some other installation issue. A normal package install should be of the type:

```
sudo apt-get install package
```

It would help if you listed the package you were actually trying to install, though.

Listed in the error was this package:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-gi_3.8.2-1+rpi1rpi2_armhf.deb
```

So perhaps try deleting that file (or moving it to another location, say /tmp) and rerun your install. If aptitude has downloaded that deb file (but it is corrupt) it could be trying to install it as a dependency. You may also delete that file and try to install "python-gi" again, or whatever that package's name is.

Answer (score 0):

Put -f (if that is the software you want to install) after the install. Like this, sudo apt-get install -f

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen with all software?
Is your initial Raspbian image corrupted maybe?
Have you checked the hash of the downloaded image?

If not, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148383/how-to-resolve-dpkg-error-processing-var-cache-apt-archives-python-apport-2-0) thread may be of some use: